# Where do created file go? (AT&T Assembly I/O)

Tags: assembly, file-io, x86-64, att

I am learning AT&T Assembly creating files. I ran the code needed to create a text file, `foo.txt`, but there was no file in my system(or at least not that finder can find). So is there something wrong with the code or is the file somewhere hidden?

Note that the my `pwd` is `/Users/mac/Desktop` and the code is in `/Users/mac/Desktop`.

Code:

```
.data
file_name:
    .asciz      "foo.txt"

.text

.globl _main
_main:
    pushq       %rbp
    movq        %rsp, %rbp

    movq        $8, %rax                # Set sys_create
    leaq        file_name(%rip), %rbx   # Set file name to f_name
    movq        $0777, %rcx             # Set file permissions
    syscall

    leave
    ret
```

Comment: It is operating system specific. On Linux and POSIX systems, file with *relative* paths like "foo.txt" are created in the *current working directory* . On Linux, use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the system calls done by a program. On MacOSX, look into [dtruss](https://opensourcehacker.com/2011/12/02/osx-strace-equivalent-dtruss-seeing-inside-applications-what-they-do-and-why-they-hang/)

Comment: Doesn't the AMD64 ABI, including its system calls, pass parameters through `RDI`/`RSI` instead of `RBX`/`RCX`

Comment: @doynax, thanks for your suggestion but it is to no avail.

Comment: @Moon Cheesez: These seem to be be Linux i386 syscall numbers and register assignments. You'll need to work out the OSX (or FreeBSD) equivalents.

Comment: According to [this](https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/) (although its NASM), the `RDI / RSI` instead of `RBX / RCX` is the correct one for Mac OSX